# Selenium is not click to date

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, calendar

```
chDriver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");    
chDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='travel_date']")).click();                                           
        List<WebElement> datesL = chDriver.findElements(By.className("day"));                                          
        int countDays = chDriver.findElements(By.className("day")).size();
        for (int i = 0; i < countDays; i++)
        {
            String dateTxt = chDriver.findElements(By.className("day")).get(i).getText();
            if (dateTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("28"))
            {
                chDriver.findElements(By.className("day")).get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

I'm studying on Selenium, this code block is taken from Udemy course, but it's not work for me. I don't understand why.
If is working properly but not click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed break and it's work properly.

```
if (dateTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("32"))
        {
            chDriver.findElements(By.className("day")).get(i).click();
        }
    }
```